# Given the full path to a file, how do I get just the path without the filename?

Tags: regex, perl

Suppose I have a path  in a string called '/home/user/directory/HelloWorld.txt'. I would like to remove the HelloWorld.txt, and end up with '/home/user/directory'. What regex would I need.

Comment: Using a regex is the wrong solution here.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use a regex. Instead, use **[`File::Basename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)**, which can handle all the special cases.

```
use File::Basename;

dirname("/foo/bar/baz/quux.txt"); --> "/foo/bar/baz"
```

Comment: And File::Basename will handle Windows file names where the average regex won't.

Comment: From the documentation you linked to:

"`dirname` This function is provided for compatibility with the Unix shell command dirname(1) and has inherited some of its quirks. In spite of its name it does NOT always return the directory name as you might expect. To be safe, if you want the directory name of a path use fileparse()."

Comment: @Kinopiko: It'll work for all reasonable cases. But yes, fileparse is just as good.

Comment: Except that the author of the question needs another function, basename(), not dirname(). Basename() will return the file name (rather than the path to parent).

Comment: @kirillka : Unless I'm misunderstanding something, he wants just the path. "I would like to remove the HelloWorld.txt, and end up with '/home/user/directory'."

Comment: And `dirname` will handle VMS where the filename format is DISK$SOMETHING:[DIR.DIR]FILE.EXT

Answer (score 0):

split on "/", remove last element and join them back.

```
$path='/home/user/directory/HelloWorld.txt';
@s = split /\// ,$path;
pop(@s);
print join("/",@s);
```