# Perl, how to get the directory path from this full path?

Tags: regex, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Given the full path to a file, how do I get just the path without the filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582132/given-the-full-path-to-a-file-how-do-i-get-just-the-path-without-the-filename)

My full path can have these types of patterns. How can I get the directory path?

```
file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\d_param_ZRK176E
file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\p_param_HCB@002.txt
file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\p_param_QCB@B006.1.txt
```

Thanks
Jirong

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't hard, especially with so many file path modules on CPAN around [[1](https://metacpan.org/module/Path%3a%3aClass)][[2](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec)]. Also, the parts of a path are better seperated by forward slashes.

Comment: I also like using the `fileparse` function from [File::Basename module](http://search.cpan.org/~dom/perl-5.12.5/lib/File/Basename.pm) for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, there are many CPAN modules you can use, which means you can avoid doing string manipulations. E.g.

```
use File::Basename 'fileparse';

my @files = qw(
    file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\d_param_ZRK176E
    file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\p_param_HCB@002.txt
    file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\p_param_QCB@B006.1.txt
);

my @dirs = map { (fileparse($_))[1] } grep { s/^file=// } @files;
print join "\n", @dirs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your problem

```
my @list = qw(
  file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\d_param_ZRK176E
  file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\p_param_HCB@002.txt
  file=M:\ccadm01_IACB_DEV\Informatica_AVOB\IACB_src\parm\p_param_QCB@B006.1.txt
);

for my $line (@list) {
  my @split_path =  split(/\\/, $line);
  for my $i (1..$#split_path) {
    print @split_path[$i], "/";
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: why not `print join("/", @split_path[1 .. $#split_path-1]), "\n";` – no need for a loop with array slices. Also fixes one-off error: you include the filename in the output! (e.g. `ccadm01_IACB_DEV/Informatica_AVOB/IACB_src/parm/p_param_HCB@002.txt/`)